# Passing parameters from Javascript to Android (Java)

Tags: java, javascript, android, android-intent

I'm trying to send an email through the Android's email client. However, when I attempt to send the E-mail to the client, it says the email is null. I find that strange since I'm passing the correct parameters in JavaScript, but the app wont read it?

I have been researching this issue for awhile now and have searched Stack Overflow for awhile.

Anyways, my goal with this is to understand why my parameters are not being passed through.

JavaScript:

```
    function sendEmailToAndroid (emailAddresses, CC, subject) {
        alert(emailAddresses); //This displays the correct address
        if (IsAndroidDevice()) {
            window.ccs.sendEmail(emailAddresses, CC, subject);
        }
    }
```

Java:

```
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void sendEmail(String[] emailAddress, String[] CC, String subject){
        Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailAddress);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        email.setType("message/rfc822");

        if(emailAddress == null || emailAddress.length == 0){
            Toast ctoast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There is no email for this customer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            ctoast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            ctoast.show();

            Log.d(LOG, "Email: "+emailAddress);
        }
        else{
            try{
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Send mail..."));
            } catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to initalize email client!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now when I debug the JavaScript, all parameters are being passed correctly. However, when it is read in the android app, all the values come back as null, or undefined. Which is not correct.

Comment: I would not be the least bit surprised if you cannot pass `String[]` from JavaScript to Java. If there is only one address of each, use `String`. If there is really more than one, consider converting the collection to a single `String` (encode to JSON, or concatenate using some character that is invalid for email addresses).

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm not passing a `String[]` from Javascript to Java

Comment: The first and second parameters of your `sendEmail()` method signature are `String[]`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am passing a String from Javascript into the method of java requiring String[]. So in theory it should work without issues, correct?

Comment: "So in theory it should work without issues, correct?" -- I certainly would not assume so. If you are passing a string, make the parameter to the Java method be `String`, not `String[]`.